# jquery replace row in table with fadein/fadeout

Tags: jquery

I have a table which I want to update a single row in after an ajax update has completed.  The rows all have an id which is the line number of the order.  I've tried a variety of things, but no joy.

This is the current command...

```
wsHtml += '<tr id="idLine'+data[0].ORDS1_LINE+'">';
wsHtml += '<td class="RightNoWrap"  >' + data[0].ORDS1_LINE + '</td>';
.....
wsHtml += '</tr>';

$('#idLine'+data[0].ORDS1_LINE).fadeOut(1000,function(){ $(this).html(wsHtml).fadeIn(1000); });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better to remove the old `<tr>` from the DOM completely, and add in a new one at its position. This should work:

```
var the_new_row = $('<tr id="idLine'+data[0].ORDS1_LINE+'">\
                         <td class="RightNoWrap"  >' + data[0].ORDS1_LINE + '</td>\
                     </tr>');

$('#idLine' + data[0].ORDS1_LINE).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    the_new_row.insertAfter($(this)).hide();
    $(this).remove();
    the_new_row.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/ckvgu/

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

wsHtml should contains only the innerHTML of element. So you don't need to append tr tags,

If your code works, you can get a result like this,

```
<tr id="idLine223">
<tr id="idLine223">
<td class="RightNoWrap">223</td>
</tr>
</tr>
```

**Solution:**

Remove the lines that you append tr tags.

```
wsHtml += '<td class="RightNoWrap"  >' + data[0].ORDS1_LINE + '</td>';
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

TR rows can not animate directly. I suggest you these steps:

1. create a one line table with same styling with the row on-the-fly, and position it over the row which should be animated.
2. get the row's content with `.contents()` method of jQuery,
3. append the content to the newly created table
4. animate and change content of this table,
5. then rebind the content to its relevant row and remove the temp table.